# Will the software interrupt with each other, if I install e.g.opencv locally, but administrator account already installed one?

Tags: software-installation, administrator

I am planning to install opencv in the local account. But administrator already has one. Will the new one cover the old automatically? Will the configuration be changed in administrator account, even if I change it in local account?

Thanks! :)